# What does `ls` really return?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Very noob question, I started using Linux 3 days ago so please bear with me :)

I don't really understand the structure of the data returned by many shell commands. Let me explain better:

Whenever I run commands such as `ls`, what is exactly being returned? And by returned, I don't mean what is printed on screen but rather what's in memory. Can I use the output returned from `ls` for instance? Or does this command return `null` and just prints things on screen? How can I check the data that is being returned?

And more generally, where can I check what does each command return?

Thank you!

Comment: Please try not to use the output of `ls` for anything. [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: `ls` is a tool for *users* to interact with to get a list of files and as such what it prints is all you get out of it. What it does under the hood is use system calls and there is nothing stopping you writing you own program that uses the same calls but gives different outputs. The thing is though that the output of `ls` is complete and consistent enough that you can read it yourself and then sensibly chain it together with other commands to strip, process, and do things with that output. The command you see simply prints the directory listing in human readable format as user1686 says below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is what you get, really. Everything that was printed after running `ls` was printed by the 'ls' command itself – there was *no* intermediate return value that had to be reformatted.

Shell commands aren't exactly like functions in programming languages – they cannot return anything but a single integer: the "exit status". Most shells allow inspecting this value through the `$?` variable. (The convention is to return 0 on success; 1 or greater on failure.)

So literally all output you're seeing is produced not through a return value, but by writing ordinary text to the special files called "stdout" and "stderr" *during* the execution of the command (the former is meant for regular output, the latter for notices and error messages).

Of course, *inside* the 'ls' program you would find calls to libc functions such as readdir() which returns a `struct dirent`, or stat() which returns a `struct stat`. However, none of those are returned to the outside world.

So can you use the output of 'ls'? In a sense yes, in fact much of the traditional "Unix" user interface is built upon the idea using one program's output as another program's input – that's what the `|` pipe operator is for. However, keep in mind that the 'ls' output is specifically formatted for human consumption and is *not* easily machine-parseable. In other words, you *shouldn't* use the output of 'ls' in scripts even if you can.

(Piping works best when the initial program was actually written to produce somewhat structured output. For this reason, many tools can actually be run with options to output either pretty formatted text *or* machine-parseable text. Compare `lsblk` vs `lsblk --raw` vs `lsblk --json`.)

---

There are exceptions – there have been shells which attempt to support flexible return types, but PowerShell is the only widely known example. PowerShell cmdlets can return arbitrary .NET Runtime types.

Comment: Amazing answer, precisely what was being asked. Thank you!